# How to build a Linked_list_builder function in C

Tags: c

I am learning about linked list, I want to make a function which creates a linked list, after that I want to make a for loop which will print our linked list at main function.
I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct linked_list {
    int data;
    struct linked_list* link;
}node;


//building list 

node linked_list_builder(int length) {
    node* list;
    list = (node*) malloc(length * sizeof(node));
    
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        printf("Data in list no.%d at index %d = ",i+1,i);
        scanf("%d",list->data);
        list->link += 1; 
    }
    return *list;
}
 
int main() {
    int length;
    printf("Enter the length of Linked list:\n");
    scanf("%d", &length);

    node list = linked_list_builder(length);

    //printing list
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        printf("index %d->list %d = %d\n",i,i+1,list.data);
        list.link++;
    }

    return 0
}
```

I don't know what's the exact problem, I don't know how can I return my linked list from function, and How can I actually travel it and print its data?

Comment: "*I don't know what's the exact problem*". Can you please update the question with what specific error or incorrect behaviour you get?

Comment: You need one allocation for every value stored in the linked list. Now, look at your code. how many *alllocations* (e.g. `malloc`) are executed? Also, `linked_list_builder` leaks memory of the one allocation you actually *did* do. Finally, what was the plan when you did `list->link += 1;` ? Whatever reference showed you that was either hideous or misunderstood.

Comment: `scanf("%d",list->data);` you need to pass the address of `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

As pointed out by @WhozCraig:

You are reserving space for all nodes at once, if that were possible, you would have no need to create a list (with its handicap of memory fragmentation and also needing an extra pointer to point to the next node) and in that case it would be enough to use an array.

A list is useful when you don't know the number of elements you need beforehand. If you really need a list, store the position of the first element of the list in a variable (`head`) and add elements to that list one by one through a `push` function:

```
node *linked_list_push(node *tail, int data) {
    node *curr = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
    
    curr->data = data;
    if (tail != NULL) {
        tail->link = curr;
    }
    return curr;
}

node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
// pushing list
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    tail = linked_list_push(tail, i);
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tail;
    }
}
// printing list
while (head) {
    node *temp = head;

    printf("%d\n", head->data);
    head = head->link;
    free(temp);
}
```

And as pointed out by @Kuro:

`scanf` wants a pointer:

```
scanf("%d",list->data);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d",&list->data);
```